# Excel vba macro gets type mismatch error in 2007 but works in 2010

Tags: excel, vba, types, foreach, mismatch

I made and tested this macro in Excel 2010 on Windows 7, also tested with another Windows 7 computer but with Excel 2007.  Worked on both, but when I try to use it on my work computer (Windows 7, Excel 2007) I get the "type mismatch error" at the first "Next" statement.  Looked up and found I could use "Exit For" instead of "next" but then it just complains about the next line that contains "End If".  Now it claims "End If without block If".  I guess I just can't understand how this worked on one Win7\Excel 2007 computer but not the other.

The macro simply searches for the values of the selected cells in email subjects(if the cell isn't already colored), if there is a match, it changes the color of the cell.

```
Sub MultipleCellSubjectSearch()

'This macro searches for the selected cell values (if there is no cell color), when it finds a match it turns the cell color yellow

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olItem As MailItem
Dim olInbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oCell As Range

'The following sets the Outlook folder to search
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'The following searches for cell value string in subject
For Each oCell In Selection
    If oCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone Then
        For Each olItem In olInbox.Items
            If InStr(olItem.Subject, (oCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
            oCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNamespace = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

If anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you are using a different version of Outlook on both machines? Are you including the right references? This is more an "environment" issue than a difference in Excel, I suspect...

Comment: By the way... an `Exit For` is a great way to break out of a loop early - but you still need to have a "regular" end to your loop. So it is not a case of "replace `Next` with `Exit For`, but more: `For... do stuff... if something then exit for... do more stuff... Next`. Make sense?

Comment: Both of the Excel 2007 machines run outlook 2007, on Windows 7 Pro.  I have the exact same references included on both.  I guess to elaborate more, I need to find a way to get this working on my "company" computer.  I would imagine it is some simple change I could make that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a thought - your `olItem` is defined as a `mailItem`. It is possible that the code fails when your next item in the mailbox is not a mail item? Would a calendar request or something else cause this? You might want to put a Debug.Print statement in the inner loop to see what objects are being looked at - and see if the loop does in fact execute until it comes across a strange item in your inbox...

As a quick fix, if you allowed it to be a variant, you would not get a type error. So you would just declare it as

```
Dim olItem
```

without the `as mailItem`

It's a long shot.

Comment: Happy to see the "long shot" answer accepted - I wonder if you can comment on what you actually found? What was the item that caused the problem?

Comment: That worked!! My work email has meeting requests, etc. in it that must have been killing the loop.  The other machines that I had tested on only have mail items in the inbox, so that would explain why it worked on those test computers.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I guess I was lucky. Thanks for the additional information - I think it makes the question/answer ultimately more useful for future SO users.